# Time Machine restored Catalina rather than Big Sur

Tags: macbook-pro, time-machine

I made a Time Machine backup to a hard drive using the latest Big Sur version (11.5.1). I've just bought a 13-inch 2020 Macbook Pro (not M1) and to my horror, restoring this backup did so with Catalina 10.15.5!

It seems that my files are present (thank goodness) - including those just before the backup. Strangely, the latest version of Xcode is also present - but refuses to run since the MacOS version is too old!

I'm really struggling to find anything else on the internet addressing this problem - and would like to know what is going on. I hope that nothing else has gone wrong. Should I manually now update this to Big Sur (again)? I don't want to corrupt my Time Machine Backup.

Many, many thanks.

Comment: How did you do a  restore of macOS? Tmdoes not restore the os

Comment: This is a new device just bought (upgrading the old one). Could it be that it comes with Catalina by default? It's a 2020 (not M1) Macbook Pro. Thanks!

Comment: So it had catalina on before you used time machine. So you use d tmvia migration a ssistant?

Comment: Ah I see... Yes I used migration assistant when going through the usual new macbook setup sequence.

Comment: Don't turn ™ on. First try to install big Sur. If that does not work then start from scratch and install big Sur before using migration assistant

Comment: Yes that makes a lot of sense. I'll try that now, thanks so much!